# How to deploy custom assembly in SSRS in Production Environment

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have created one custom assembly and this assembly uses a third party assembly.
I have deployed a custom assembly in my local machine. But now, what should I do to deploy the report and those assemblies in the production environment. Is there any automated/wizard process available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to copy that assemblies to production server into 
`Microsoft SQL Server\MSSRS\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin` folder.
Then back to ReportServer folder and open `rssrvpolicy.config` file to grant FullTrust permission to `CodeGroup` with name `Report_Expressions_Default_Permissions` and `CodeGroup` with class name `FirstMatchCodeGroup`.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy your library to the ReportServer\Bin folder
ex: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.R2\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin

Then modify the rssrvpolicy.config in ReportServer folder, find "$CodeGen$" and add the following code

```
<CodeGroup
    class="UnionCodeGroup"
    version="1"
    PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
    Name="CoDeMagSample"
    Description="CoDe Magazine Sample. ">
   <IMembershipCondition
        class="UrlMembershipCondition"
        version="1"
        Url="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.R2\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\YOURLIBRARY.dll"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool for that. It's called [Reporting Services Scripter](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62)

Another option is to connect to your production server through `SSRS`.