# SSRS "not in" takes an extremely time if at all to run

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

SSRS - SQL 2008 SSRS Version 3.0.
Need to run a NOT IN, but takes an extremely long time to run

Have seen the "Stacia" post about using a filter and I don't seem to have it right.
http://blog.datainspirations.com/2011/01/20/working-with-reporting-services-filters-part-4-creating-a-not-in-filter/

In the Tablix of the report, I have put in the for the Filter the following:

```
=Iif(InStr(Join(Parameters!FilterList.Value,","),Fields!Status.Value)=0,True,False)
```

What I am trying to do is to show records that are not Cancelled.

Even doing a simple filter:

- Expression: [Status]
- Operator <>
- Value Cancelled

Still seems to take an extremely long time.

We could have the following Status conditions:

- Cancelled
- Closed
- Open
- Resolved

If I take this the opposite way and look for all tickets that are cancelled (filter) in SSRS, the results come back pretty quickly.

UPDATE: if I put in the Filter for the Query for the Report:

- Closed
- Open
- Resolved

And just simply leave Cancelled out, that should work OK.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your filter on the Group, the MATRIX or the dataset? It might run quicker on the dataset since it would only check once. The problem depends on how many records you have though - the checks have to be made for each row.

You can try doing an **IN** statement to see if it's any faster. Create a new dataset that has the **Status** values but excludes the chosen one(s).

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 'Cancelled' AS STATUS_TYPE 
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Resolved' 
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Open' 
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Closed' ) AS X 
WHERE STATUS_TYPE NOT IN (@StatusType)
```

Then create another parameter based on the dataset with the available and default values as the **Status_Type** column. You can make it hidden when you get it working so users won't see it if it does work faster.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the root cause to make reports running slowly. Can you try to add this rule into a library then include it in report? 
You can ref at

[How to deploy custom assembly in SSRS in Production Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600488/how-to-deploy-custom-assembly-in-ssrs-in-production-environment/32643867#32643867)

http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-reporting-services/custom-programming-enhance-ssrs-reports

Comment: Sorry - Custom Assembly is not going to work as I am just a user of the SSRS in our prod server (which is basically an SharePoint installation)..  So corporate is not going to allow that.  The custom programming link - that maybe helpful as I have been desperately trying to figure out a way to not send reports if there is no data within.

Comment: I have just looked into your post again. You can create a report variable such as FilterValues, to store values of your FilterList, then implement a custom code in report to check if the status is in the FilterValues or not. The problem is that you always combine values from your filter in the Tablix, thus, the report take time to calculate and render. Hope this help.