# SSRS-> .RDL -> Report Properties -> Code - VB Questions -> Encrypt

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I'm interested in writing code in the Custom Code section of SSRS Report Properties in a .RDL file.

I need to use `SimpleAES` functions inside a Library called `System.Security.Cryptography` as I'm going to attempt to create an encrypt function on a field value in the report.

I need the libraries:

```
System.IO
System.Text
System.Security.Cryptography
```

Can someone explain how I can add these libraries or where they might be located in the Assemblies? Or if it's even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add reference to these assembly in Report Properties, tab Reference.

Comment: Ok, but I'm only seeing System.IO.log the other two don't exist in the library...I understand you add the assembly from the libraries, but what if the library doesn't exist, do I need to download it from somewhere?

Comment: Plus, as I understand it, you can only write functions in the custom code. So once added, how would I implement this into the Custom Code section?

Comment: In SSRS custom code, you have to implement your function using VB syntax. With System.Text, you can use in your code without reference, ex:    `Dim strBuilder As New System.Text.StringBuilder(s)`. With other library, If you find it difficult to use in custom code, you can implement a custom library then add that library to report server and reference to your report and use.
You can see how to add new library into Report Server at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600488/how-to-deploy-custom-assembly-in-ssrs-in-production-environment/32643867#32643867